# Updating an Imported Object

Tags: python

Suppose `file_A.py` is written as so:

```
#file_A.py

my_object = create_new_object()

def update_object():
    global my_object
    my_object = update(my_object)
```

and then in `file_B.py` we do as so:

```
#file_B.py

from file_A import my_object, update_object

def process_object(object):
    #do some operation ...


process_object(my_object) #first call to process_object()
update_object()
process_object(my_object) #second call to process_object()
```

My question is, when the second call to `process_object()` is made, will it use the original version of `my_object` ,which is imported at the top of `file_B.py`, be used, or will it use the updated version which replaces `my_object` when the `update_object()` function is called from `file_B.py`?

Comment: @flakes that makes a lot of sense, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are passed by reference. In `file_A` you will update the modules reference to `my_object` but the value imported in `file_B` will still have the old reference. For example:

Say I have file `testA.py`

```
a = 1
def foo():
    global a
    a = 2
```

And `testB.py`

```
from testA import a, foo

print(a)
foo()
print(a)
```

If I run `testB.py` you will get the output `1,1`

This is because the `global` only updated the reference attached to the module `testA.py`. If you were to access the module however, then you would see it did update there. An example where you access the module instead

`testC.py`

```
import testA

print(testA.a)
testA.foo()
print(testA.a)
```

This will output `1, 2`

Answer (score 1):

Note that the same variable (even if global) can have different values in different python modules. Thus the best way to reference a variable from another module is by using `module.variable`
So your code might look like

```
import file_A

print(file_A.my_object)
file_A.process_object(file_A.my_object)
file_A.process_object(file_A.my_object)
print(file_A.my_object)
```

The key to referencing the right variable is to use the module name.
This can also be useful when you are working with multiple files and you need to keep some global variables.

Comment: I wouldn't really say that this is "the best way". Generally you don't want to have global state in the first place, or if the item you want to reference is mutable, then you would want to use a getter function to access the value, or use a variable where the class provides a mutable container. i.e. appending to the contents of a global dict wouldn't cause this issue (although, again, global mutable state is not recommended in the first place). In this case you are using the module as this container for the reference.